# CouchDB 2 on Windows 7 crashes on startup when SSL is enabled

Tags: ssl, couchdb, windows-7-x64

I've just installed CouchDB on my machine for testing with StackEdit, which needs SSL.

CouchDB starts fine after a fresh install.

But when I try to enable SSL with a self-signed certificate, as explained [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48203146), CouchDB won't start.

Here's what the log says:

```
[error] 2016-09-29T16:16:01.402000Z couchdb@localhost <0.201.0> -------- Error starting Apache CouchDB:

    {error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,httpsd,{'EXIT',{badarg,[{erlang,'++',[undefined,"."],[]},{couch_util,parse_term,1,[{file,"src/couch_util.erl"},{line,164}]},{couch_httpd,start_link,1,[{file,"src/couch_httpd.erl"},{line,46}]},{supervisor,do_start_child,2,[{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,314}]},{supervisor,start_children,3,[{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,297}]},{supervisor,init_children,2,[{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,263}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,306}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}}}}}}}
```

full log [here](https://framabin.org/?8a3d4dd02cace0fa#XkdoK/WtuQ+VgQXgQ6tlgU8CFitwYq3CRBKvhE+IexY=).

My CouchDB sits in C:\CouchDB.
I've put the key and certificate files there too.

My OpenSSL version is 1.0.2d.

Answer (score 5):

As @Robin mentions, there is a [bug in CouchDB 2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-3162)

For me, it was a matter of adding the following lines in local.ini:

```
[ssl] 
ciphers = undefined 
tls_versions = undefined 
secure_renegotiate = undefined 

[daemons]
httpsd = {chttpd, start_link, [https]}
```

And, another important detail is that SSL support in CouchDB 2 appears to be broken when using Erlang versions before 18.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/couchdb-user-archive/cBrZ25DHHVA for more info.

Comment: I've been trying to make it work with self signed certificates, but no cigar.
I give up. I'm not even using StackEdit anymore.
Thanks for the information. I hope it will be of some use to others.

Comment: @VictorToulouse I also just discovered that you need Erlang >= 18. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Those SSL settings were what fixed it for me. Awesome :)

Answer (score 3):

I was faced with this issue for the last 2 days and found out it was a bug in CouchDB 2.0.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-3162

Hopefully it will really be fixed on V2.0.1